# as3 dynamic index change for added objects on stage

Tags: actionscript-3

I have added some backgrounds on stage and then on top of that adding another background and all these are movieclips.

At some time i have to remove the backgrounds and then it should be added but here problem am facing is the background become coming front.

so is there any function like send to back or bring to frond based on the movie clip names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to experiment with :

```
setChildIndex(object, z-value)
```

This set the depth of the object on the stage.

```
swapChildren (object1, object2)
```

This exchange the position of two objects on the stage.

- [setChildIndex](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29)
- [swapChildren](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildren%28%29)
- [swapChildrenAt](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildrenAt%28%29)
- [addChildAt](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt%28%29)

Comment: +1. I've edited in links to relevant functions - didn't see any point in posting another answer just for links.

Comment: thanks, setChildIndex helped me to fixed the problem. I just did this . p.setChildIndex(controls,p.numChildren - 1);

Answer (score 0):

Use addChildAt(index);

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt()